# Does dark matter experience drag?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, drag, dark-matter, galaxies

Is dark matter dragged around the galaxy by gravity as stars and groups of stars orbit the galaxy, and, if so, is its shape/distribution deformed?  Similarly, would the Oort cloud be deformed by being dragged around the galaxy?

Comment: "Experiencing drag" and "being dragged around by gravity" are usually used in very different senses. Usually when you speak of an object as "experiencing drag," it's slowing down by moving through a fluid or equivalent. The phrase you're looking for is probably "experiencing tidal forces."

Comment: "Experiencing tidal forces" is a clear description of the physics that I could see only obscurely - because I'm not a physicist.  I appreciate having access to experts.